# How do I clone everything inside a tabpage in code while creating a new tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, gecko

In winforms I am creating a browser based off of Gecko and I need the `geckoBrowser1`, `urlBar1 (not yet added)` and `back/forwardArrow1 (not yet added)` to be added to a new tabPage upon it's creation. My issue is copying these particular assets

I've already tried looking things up on google but they all talk about how to add a new tabpage from scratch.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //newTab is the "New Tab" button
        GeckoWebBrowser geckoWebBrowser1 = new GeckoWebBrowser();
        string title = "tabPage" + (tabControl1.TabCount + 1).ToString();
        TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(title);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
        //I want to add the geckoWebBrowser1 into a new tab here

        if (newTab.Location.X < Form1.ActiveForm.Width - 50)
        {
            newTab.Location = new Point(60 * tabControl1.TabCount - 2, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            newTab.Location = new Point(newTab.Location.X, newTab.Location.Y);
        }
    }
```

I expect the new tab I create to then take the Gecko browser and duplicate it into the new tab.

Comment: I looks like you should wrap your browser controls into a UserControl and/or create CustomControl based on TabPage.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
tabPage.Controls.Add(geckoWebBrowser1);
```

Comment: It doesn't flag up any errors, but it seems when I open the new tab nothing has changed since i added that code.